# An Error message occurs on command prompt while generating Dashboard from Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have started using JMeter 3.1 recently for load testing, all I wanted to do was generate a report dashboard from a csv file.

When I run the following command from Command Prompt:

```
jmeter -g (csv file location) -o (Destination folder to save HTML Dashboard)
```

I get the error shown below:

```
Could not parse timestamp<1.487+12> using format defined by property.saveservice.timestamp+format=ms on sample 1.487+12 .........
```

I have also attached the screenshot of the error message kindly refer below:

[image: Error on Command Prompt]

Below is my saveservice properties that I copied into user properties file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time = true
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
# the timestamp format must include the time and should include the date.
# For example the default, which is milliseconds since the epoch: 
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms
# Or the following would also be suitable
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
#save service assertion
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message = true
```

I am not able to figure out the resaon, any help in this regard will be much appreciated.
please help, also please let me know if any addition information is required.

I have followed the below link to generate Dashboard:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: looks like time stamp is the problem, can you send time stamp value from your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question itself:

> Could not parse timestamp<1.487+12>

According to your configuration, JMeter expects first column to be in [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format like `1487047932355` (time since beginning of Unix epoch in milliseconds)

Another supported format is `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` like `2017/02/14 05:52:12.355`

So there are several constraints:

- The value of `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms` should be the same during test execution and dashboard generation
- You need to **restart** JMeter to pick the properties up. For example if you ran the test, then amended properties and then tried to generate dashboard - it might fail
- There are no duplicate properties
- You don't do anything with the .jtl results file between test execution and dashboard generation

My expectation is that you opened .jtl results file with MS Excel which converted timestamps into [scientific notation](https://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan) and saved so most probably you will be able to do the opposite.

Just in case I would also recommend getting familiarised with [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: As rightly pointed by you, MS Excel converts timestamp into Scientific Notation, if you open the csv file in notepad/notepad++ timestamp is rendered in ms.
The issue was resolved after changing the timestamp format to dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

The default timestamp format in JMeter csv and logs is given in a Unix style format , but you can change it .

1. Go to `(jmeterDirectory)/bin` .
2. open `jmeter.properties` file .
3. Search for the following :-

   `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format`
4. You will find it commented (Start with #) . Uncomment it and restart the Jmeter .
5. You can update this above property with the format you need